# How to make jQuery AJAX request with a HTTP Handler in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, httphandler

I'm developing a SP 2010 Visual Web Part that needs to load some data via AJAX.

I found [this very helpful article](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/11/sp2010-ajax-part-3-using-jquery-ajax.html) but I'm having some doubts about it.

I have the Visual Web Part project, inside I have the Visual Web Part and some other files. The article says I need to create an .ashx file that will acts as an HTTP handler.
So that's what I did, I created a "MyHandler.ashx" in the root of the project and put the `WebHandler` directive. But I'm not sure about the `Assembly` directive.

Then it says we need to create an implementation to the handler and point it to it. I believe I have that part ok.

Then I need to make the actual client call via jQuery. Here's the part I don't know how to do it because I don't know the url where the .ashx is being deployed (if it's even being deployed...).

I'm trying:

```
$.get('/_layouts/SomeNamespace/MyHandler.ashx', ...)
```

But it's not working... again, don't know the handler's url...

I'm pretty new at Sharepoint development, so please don't be harsh =)

Thanks!

Here are simplified versions of my handler's files.

**MyHandler.ashx**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="SomeNamespace.MyHandler" CodeBehind="MyHandler.cs" %>
```

**MyHandler.cs**

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }


        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Write("From the handler at " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        // bunch of methods
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I created a "MyHandler.ashx" in the root of the project

You have to deploy **MyHandler.ashx** to **_layouts/SomeNamespace/** folder. Use **Add** -> **SharePoint "_Layouts" Mapped Folder** in Visual Studio Solution Explorer.

Comment: That was exactly what I was missing. Thanks!